# My $el is not working?

Tags: javascript, templates, backbone.js, underscore.js

I am trying to learn Backbone and I have a few views that are working just fine.  Here is the code from my problematic view:

```
var FavoritesView = Backbone.View.extend({
        el: 'favs',
        render: function() {
            var timesheets = new TimeSheet();
            var $that = $(this);
            timesheets.fetch({
                data: { favorite: true},
                success: function(model, response, options) {
                    var template = _.template($('#favs-view').html(), { timesheets: model.models})
                    $('.favs').html(template).addClass('well');
                }
            });
        }
      });
```

You can see that I fetch a collection, put the response in a template, and then display it.  I am not able to get the $el from inside my 'success' callback.  $that.el and $that.$el (I don't know the difference) are both undefined.  I had to eventually use Jquery to get the element and attach the template as you see.  This is working, but this is a hack and I dont like it.  Any help would be great.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I take it `favs` is a class or an id. Try adding a `.` if it's a class or a `#` if it's an id, right before `favs`, like `el: '.favs',`. It's jquery selector syntax.

Answer (score 1):

I think you are doing wrong in this line

```
var $that = $(this);
```

el is property of **this** object not of **$(this)**.
So you should just do

```
var that = this;
```

Then this.el won't be undefined. Check this [working example](http://jsbin.com/akovun/2/edit)

**Difference between this.el and this.$el**

Basically $el is cached jquery object of $(this.el). Read more at [Backbone View Documentation](http://backbonejs.org/#View-%24el)

Comment: `$(this)` is just wrapped `this` object

Comment: ohh you are right. my mistake! and he will need to change `favs` to `.favs`

Comment: Yes, Well I thought it was typo in his code So I didn't mention it in my answer :|